# Multiple Tables Finding Correct Results Issues

Tags: mysql

I'm stuck on this one and looking for developer feedback - your help will be hugely appreciated!

Firstly I'm not the greatest at MySQL so I'm struggling my way through each query but I'm hoping you guys could confirm the correct tables I need to solve my problem.

I have a filled out "users" table with data already.

The general gist is I need to have voting system for a project I'm putting together and it's hurting my head at this point as to what tables I need to be at least 3rd normal form.

A user can vote on another user, I need this recorded so that the user1 who voted on user2 can never re-vote on user2 again.

I hope to be able to recall these votes & display on the website.

I have 3 tables created other than "users" but I think this can be done better with your help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest construction would probably be to just have your existing user table and add a `votes` table to keep track of the votes;

```
CREATE TABLE votes (
  user_who_voted INT NOT NULL,
  user_who_received_vote INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX only_one_vote
ON votes(user_who_voted, user_who_received_vote);
```

The unique index will keep track of that votes are unique, a second vote on the same person will fail.

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f084a/14) for an example how it works.

Comment: That's cool I'll try and implement this in the morning and let you know how it goes. I made so much progress today and just hit this minor road block!

Comment: I've ended up with 4 tables in total, users, votes, whose_voted & user_votes